# Do I REALLY need to implement IEnumerable? What is System.Collections.IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, generics, iterator, ienumerable

I have two questions:

**First question:**

I wrote a Scanner which generates a stream of tokens on demand by a Parser.

```
public class Scanner
{
    public IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator()
    { //DO SOME STUFF HERE
      yield return new Token(...);
    }
}

public class Parser
{
    IEnumerator<Token> iterator;
    ...
    public Parser(Scanner scanner)
    {
        this.iterator = scanner.GetEnumerator(); 
        ...
    }
    public Token nextToken()
    {
        //generate the next token
        iterator.MoveNext();//there is no need to test MoveNext()
        return iterator.Current;//get the generated token
    }
    ...
}
```

Considering that this is actually the only case where I use the Scanner class in the whole framework, do you think that's ok or It would be more correct that `Scanner` implements `IEnumerable`?

If I'm not wrong, the compiler will do some operation to make Scanner implements IEnumerable anyway, is that correct?

**Second question:**

Suppose that `Scanner` implements `IEnumerable`, then the code will look like:

```
public class Scanner:IEnumerable<Token>
{
public IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator()
{
    ...
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
   return this.GetEnumerator();//I'M NOT SURE OF THIS!
}
```

What I do not understand is what is the meaning of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and if my implementation is correct or not. I know that it is necessary since `Scanner` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumerable` (otherwise GetEnumerator() would be sufficient, but then on `Current` I should do an inefficient downcast from object to Token).

Can someone exaplain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`, so if you're implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you are automatically also implementing `IEnumerable`.

`IEnumerable` exists for one reason: because C# 1.0 did not have generics. Because of that, we now have to implement `IEnumerable` all the time, which is just kind of annoying.

Your implementation is correct: when implementing IEnumerable, just have it call the generic version.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
   return this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to the second question! I have two questions for you: 1. what about the first question? 2. There is any particular reason because I should implement `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` in a different way?

Comment: IEnumerable is not just a legacy. It makes available to enumerate objects. It is not generic, but it is generalized way of enumeration.

Comment: @TIKSN it is pretty much legacy. `IEnumerable<object>` is preferable because it fits in with LINQ.

Comment: @justHelloWorld A reason to implement IEnumerable is so that you can use it in a foreach loop and use LINQ and all that.

Comment: @Dennis_E you can use a foreach loop anyway (I just tried it now) ! I don't know what about LINQ

Comment: @justHelloWorld Yes, I forgot you don't actually have to implement the interface. Having the method GetEnumerator() is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `IEnumerable<T>` as distinct from `IEnumerator<T>` is to represent a sequence of values that you haven't started enumerating yet. You can store and pass it around like a container of values, and when you want to know what it contains, you can start enumerating it by calling `GetEnumerator`.

Or more usually, you'd use a `foreach` loop or LINQ methods like `Select` and `Where` to loop through it. These methods work on `IEnumerable<T>`, not on `IEnumerator<T>`.

If you only implement `IEnumerator<T>` then enumeration can only take place once, in a forwards direction. To repeat the enumeration, the user has to call your method again to create another enumerator.

So `IEnumerable<T>` is an instance of the "factory pattern". It's a factory that makes `IEnumerator<T>`.

(As for the weird detail about non-generic `IEnumerable`, that's just ancient history as @Dennis_E says. Your implementation that forwards to the generic version is perfectly standard.)

As @DmitryBychenko says in the comments, `IEnumerator<T>` is based on `IDisposable`. The `foreach` loop takes care of calling `Dispose` on it. And if the sequence is ultimately implemented by using `yield return`, `Dispose` has the effect of calling any finally blocks that have not yet executed.

Comment: Yet another reason is that `IEnumerator<T>` is `IDisposable` and so we have to close allocated resources (via `using`) when `IEnumerable<T>` hides resource allocation/freeing

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - *excellent* point - will update to mention that foreach calls `Dispose`.